# Editable GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am looking for some help to get started on creating an editable GridView in ASP, I already have everything working in a Form Application. Now my plan is to convert it to a Web application using ASP.NET. Not too hard I'd say, but I just have some trouble with my GridViews. So here is what my current application does and what I want it to do in ASP:

I created multiple GridViews, with only a single column. Then on this column, rows will be added when the application is started, how many should be added is found in the database. Some of these rows will be filled with data from the database, some will be left empty. I already have the code for this, just need to convert it to work with ASP. I want the user to be able to edit all these rows, including the ones that are empty. These columns do nothing fancy, the user is only able to put numbers in them.

Since I'm completely new to ASP, I have no idea how to create a GridView that has empty editable rows with it. Maybe it's very simple, but a nod in the right direction would be very much appreciated! If anymore info is needed, please let me know

[What i want to do in ASP.NET](http://postimage.org/image/n880wyplp/)

Comment: I expect you're talking about ASP.NET, not Classic ASP.

Comment: Check out http://aspnetrealworldcontr.codeplex.com/, which has a fully editable Excel-style grid with frozen headers, among other things.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2006/03/02/real-world-gridview-excel-like-frozen-headers-for-asp-net-2-0.aspx

Comment: There's also a walkthrough for doing it yourself here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992036(VS.80).aspx if you don't like third-party controls, and you actually want to do it all yourself.  it's not too hard once you figure out the pieces.

Comment: Yes, I edited my tags when I saw it said Classic.

Answer (score 1):

`GridView` is one of the the most powerful control in the long line of controls since .NET released under WebForms, it is so vastly used that there are thousands of examples and tutorials to do almost everything.

Since my times learning the good things about the GridView, I always rely on 2 websites, and today I will make them my answer.

One, *I can no longer found*, was something like **The GridView Guy**, a lovely website with the best tutorials to raise the .NET control to do almost everything.

The Seconds is the famous [Matt Berseth](http://mattberseth.com/) and [all his tutorials](http://mattberseth.com/blog) surrounding not only the `GridView` but other controls as well.

> http://mattberseth.com/blog/gridview/

---

There are plenty more tutorials out there for this, like:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16769/Full-featured-Editable-GridView-Control
- http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/643-how-to-editupdatedelete-gridview.aspx
- http://aspnet-with-c-sharp.blogspot.dk/2011/02/fully-editable-gridview-in-aspnet-2.html

You just have to follow up and if you find a wall that you can't climb, assure that someone around here can help you out, just show us what you need to do, and what have you tried.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've already looked into most of the links that you posted. But what I'm trying to do is I think much simpler than what is explained in those tutorials. I've added an image to my original post to show what i want to do

Comment: all tutorials mentioned, do exactly what you have in the picture, just follow one ... Remember, that here, we don't do code, we help you when you have some difficulties accomplish something, witch, for what you asking right now, it's all the code... we don't do that!

Comment: Hmm, correct me if I'm wrong. But I don't think they do what I have in picture. I want to edit a row when I click on a cell. In these examples, they either use text from a textbox or add a Edit/Update cell to the rows. Also I'm only asking for a small example for what I have in mind, I'm in a learning process so I don't want code delivered to me ;)

Comment: Grid View Guy was moved to HighOnCoding.com http://highoncoding.com/Articles/List